# Getting a blank output when using conditional statement

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I am trying to run conditional statement through smarty using a variable named `name`, but nothing gets displayed when the php file is run. I am new to `smarty`. What could be the mistake I am making?

`Test.php`

```
<?php
    require_once('./libs/Smarty.class.php');

    $smarty = new Smarty();

    $smarty->assign('title','Title of the page');
    $smarty->assign('hello','Text displayed from smarty!!');
    $smarty->assign('name','is smarty');
    $smarty->display('./template/template.tpl');

?>
```

`Template.tpl`

```
<html>

<head> 
    <title> {$title} </title>
 </head>

<body>
    {$hello}

    {if $name eq "smarty"}
        <span> The name is : smarty</span>
    {/elseif $name eq "is smarty"}
        <span> The name is : is smarty</span>
</body>
```

Comment: `$smarty->assign('name','Your name');` ?

Comment: You are not assigning $name.

Comment: @Debflav Edited. It is still the same.

Comment: @Debflav However, if I remove the if else clause, it works fine.

Comment: check you else code i think it should be {elseif $name eq "is smarty"}<span> The name is : is smarty</span>{/if}

Comment: `{elseif $name eq "is smarty"} ... {/if}` [Smarty Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the `{if}` block in the template:

```
<html>

<head> 
    <title> {$title} </title>
 </head>

<body>
    {$hello}

    {if $name eq "smarty"}
        <span> The name is : smarty</span>
    {/elseif $name eq "is smarty"}
        <span> The name is : is smarty</span>
    {/if}   {* <------ here ---- *}
</body>
```

When nothing is displayed you can debug the templates by setting [`$smarty->error_reporting`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.error.reporting.tpl) to [`E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) before you call `display()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment of variables in-template is essentially placing application logic into the presentation that may be better handled in PHP.

$smarty->assign('name', 'is smarty');

assigned variable in smarty object only can possible to get in template.

If you give simply $name = '' then particular variable not assign to smarty template.

so please assign variable in logic and get the value in presentation

And also ensure {elseif} instead of {/elseif} and also closing {/if} statement in smarty template page

Answer (score 0):

In your .tpl file use if condition something like this

```
{if $name eq "smarty"}
        <span> The name is : smarty</span>
    {elseif $name eq "is smarty"}
        <span> The name is : is smarty</span>
    {else}
    Welcome, whatever you are.
    {/if}
```

To read more about if else in Smarty [click here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if)

Comment: Use isset($name) or $name|default:'' to escape notice from smarty